# Maya ASCII Filepath Replace

Tags: python, python-2.7, maya

My first post here but I've spent the last few weeks basically living on S.O., looking for answers and solutions. Unfortunately I have not found an answer to my current problem on here, or anywhere else, so I am hoping one of you lovely people can help me.

I am trying to batch process Autodesk Maya files from within Windows, to replace the filepaths for references, to one singular directory. At present, it just throws back a "" after I try to execute the code.

Here is my code so far - please pick holes in it as much as you want, I need to get better!

---

```
### Reference Example
# file -rdi 2 -ns "platform3_MDL_MASTER" -rfn 
# "Toyota_2000GT_Spider:Toyota2000GT_Spider_RN"
#          -typ "mayaAscii" 
# "C:/svn/TEST/previs/maya_references/Toyota_2000GT_Spider.ma";


import os

# Defining the reference paths - before and after
projectPath = "C:/projects/TEST/previs"
originalPath = "C:/projects/TEST/previs/maya_references/"
newPath = "R:/projects/FRAT/production/maya_references/"

# Makes a list of all previs files in the given directory.
previsFiles = [os.path.join(d, x)
            for d, dirs, files in os.walk(projectPath)
            for x in files if x.endswith("_PREVIS.ma")]


previsSuffix = '.ma";'
newLines = []

# Loops through each previs file found...
# for each line that contains the previsSuffix...
# and splits the filepath into a directory and a filename
# and then replaces that originalPath with the newPath.
for scene in previsFiles:
    with open(scene, "r") as fp:
        previsReadlines = fp.readlines()
        for line in previsReadlines:
            if previsSuffix in line:
                # Splits the directory from the file name. 
                lines = os.path.split(line)
                newLines = line.replace(lines[0], newPath)
        else:
            break

    with open(scene, 'w') as fw:
        previsWritelines = fw.writelines()
```

Comment: What's the error and expected output ?

Comment: I don't know what "throws back a "" " means, but `fw.writelines()` will throw an exception, because you don't give it anything to write. And you seem to throw away `newLines` every time.

Comment: @PirateX There is no error, "Terminated" get's thrown back at me in < tags (I typed them into the original message but it seems to be interpreting that as an HTML tag).

Green Cell's response has gotten it fixed for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have the adjust this to work with your script, but I hope it gives you the general idea of how to replace a reference path with another.

The original code had 2 main issues:

1) You weren't actually changing the contents. Doing `newLines =` Doesn't actually re-assign `previsReadlines`, so the changes weren't being recorded.

2) Nothing was being passed to write with. `writelines` needs a parameter you intend to write with.

```
# Adjust these paths to existing maya scene files.
scnPath = "/path/to/file/to/open.ma"
oldPath = "/path/to/old/file.ma"
newPath = "/path/to/new/file.ma"

with open(scnPath, "r") as fp:
    # Get all file contents in a list.
    fileLines = fp.readlines()

    # Use enumerate to keep track of what index we're at.
    for i, line in enumerate(previsReadlines):
        # Check if the line has the old path in it.
        if oldPath in line:
            # Replace with the new path and assign the change.
            # Before you were assigning this to a new variable that goes nowhere.
            # Instead it needs to re-assign the line from the list we first read from.
            fileLines[i] = line.replace(oldPath, newPath)

# Completely replace the file with our changes.
with open(scnPath, 'w') as fw:
    # You must pass the contents in here to write it.
    fw.writelines(fileLines)
```

Comment: That's fantastic. Thank you very much!! I was tearing my hair out but it seems so simple now...

Comment: No problem. If this solved your problem don't forget to mark this as solved so everyone knows it's been resolved.